# Synchronize/copy OSGB Map

Tags: sync, file-transfer

I've paid for & downloaded a map from Great Britain Ordnance Survey onto my Android phone. I want to copy it to my tablet. Can anybody tell me where (i.e. directory) the map is within the phone, or how to copy the map properly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you purchased a map direct from us on our OS MapFinder app? If so, there's advice in the FAQs on syncing downloaded maps between devices that are using a linked Google Play account: https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/shop/mapfinder/mapfinder-android-faq.html

If you've purchased an Ordnance Survey map from one of our partners rather than direct from us, you'll need to check with them on how their apps and services work though.